# Showing a complex analytic function is unbounded

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory

This was one of the problems on a previous year's Complex Analysis final exam.

Assume $f\in \mathcal O (\mathbb H )$, non-constant, and $f(\frac {i}{\sqrt n})=0, \forall n\in \mathbb N$. Prove that $f$ takes unbounded values.

What I tried so far: I tried to argue that the point $z=0$ had to be an essential singularity since the function cannot be continued to be holomorphic there (taking the value $0$), for then it would be forced to be identically the $0$ function (which it is assumed not to be). Then i squared the input domain to argue that the essential singularity must take on unbounded values in the upper-half plane somewhere near $z=0$. But, I think my reasoning is wrong because this may not be an isolated singularity at all and may be a point in the branch cut of a holomorphic function or something. I'm wondering if someone can write me up a nice proof and/or explanation about how to tackle this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a fractional linear transformation, change the domain to the unit disk. Make it so that the center of the disk is not a zero of the new function (call it $g$). Let $\{a_n\}$ be the zeros of $g$. Since $g$ is bounded, [Jensen's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula) implies that for every $r\in (0,1)$
$$
\sum_{|a_k|< r} \log \frac{r}{|a_k|} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \log |g(re^{i\theta})|\,d\theta - \log |g(0)| 
 $$
where the right hand side is bounded independently of $r$. Letting $r\to 1$, conclude that 
$$
\sum_{k} \log \frac{1}{|a_k|}<\infty
$$
or equivalently 
$$
\sum_{k}  (1-|a_k|)<\infty
$$

But the sequence $i/\sqrt{n}$ is transformed into a sequence $\{b_n\}$ such that $1-|b_n|$ is comparable to $1/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the whole process. Could you spell it out a little more? Also, I realized after the fact that we didn't go over Jensen's formula yet in the class this quarter so I'm kind of unfamiliar with it.